# How can I quickly rename an open file in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

The [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/copying-renaming-and-moving-files.html) for WebStorm says if you want to rename a file, do it in the Project Tool window. The problem is that finding a file in the Project Tool window is a hassle. If you start typing there to find the file, it won't be able to locate it unless it is in an expanded folder.

How can I easily rename a file in WebStorm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to rename file right from the editor. Try Navigate/Select In.../Project view to open a file in Project Tool window and then use Refactor/rename in its right-click menu
You can also enable the 'Autoscroll from source' Project tool window option to have the currently opened file auto-selected in the project tree

Also, Refactor/rename is available in file right-click menu in the Navigation Bar if it's enabled (View/Navigation bar)

Comment: Refactor > Rename option solved it. Thanks, I was looking for it since some time :)

Comment: If you have JetBrains keybindings, Alt-F1, 1, Shift-F6

Answer (score 8):

In addition to that, You can use the shourtcut.

Click on the file in the project window & Press the buttton Shift+F6.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the file -> Refactor -> Rename or just use Shift+F6 as a shortcut and a dialog window will open up so you can change the name.